# CodeIgniter - Pagination won't work

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I'm now trying to use Pagination in my web app but it doesn't work. When I click the links created by `$this->pagination->create_links()`, I get 404 page error instead.

Here's my controller:

```
function index($id) {   

    $this->load->library('pagination');

    if($project = $this->projects_model->get($id)) {
        $temp = $this->project_logs_model->get_by('project_id', $project->id);

        //$config = array();
        //$config['base_url'] = base_url().'projects/'.$project->id.'/';
        $config['base_url'] = current_url();
        $config['total_rows'] = $temp->num_rows();
        $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
        $config['per_page'] = 5; 
        $config['first_link'] = 'Latest';
        $config['last_link'] = 'Oldest';
        $config["num_links"] = 2;
        //$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

        $this->check_access($project);

        $this->data->current_project = $project;
        $this->data->updates = $this->project_logs_model->get_by('project_id', $project->id, $config['per_page'], $page);
        $this->data->links = $this->pagination->create_links();

        $this->view('project-main', $this->data);
    } else {
        show_404();
    }
}
```

The `$id` passed to the index is used to determine which project to view and is also used to view the project_logs for that project so I really can't remove. This means that if I'll use pagination, the page number will be the second parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're planning to use page number from your url you should do somenthing like this:

```
    function index($id) {   

        $this->load->library('pagination');
         $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
         $project = $this->projects_model->get($id);    
    if(count($project) > 0) {
            $temp = $this->project_logs_model->get_by('project_id', $project->id);

            //$config = array();
           $config['base_url'] = base_url().'projects/'.$project->id.'/'.$page;
           // $config['base_url'] = current_url();
            $config['total_rows'] = $temp->num_rows();
            $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
            $config['per_page'] = 5; 
            $config['first_link'] = 'Latest';
            $config['last_link'] = 'Oldest';
            $config["num_links"] = 2;
            //$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
            $this->pagination->initialize($config);

            $this->check_access($project);

            $this->data->current_project = $project;
            $this->data->updates = $this->project_logs_model->get_by('project_id', $project->id, $config['per_page'], $page);
            $this->data->links = $this->pagination->create_links();

            $this->view('project-main', $this->data);
        } else {
            show_404();
        }

}
```

but i'm not quite sure about your logic, i use another logic, and i use offset in urls

try this tutorial i think it's a good starting point: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-7-pagination/

Comment: it still won't work. how do you use offset in urls in pagination by the way?

Comment: @RemuDesu try http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-7-pagination/